# Acessing a JSON Object using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have the following JSON object

```
({
    "codes": [ {
            "code": {
                "redeemed": "true", "retailer": "R1", "code": "ab11845b55b3ef1c3f137a35dbdfb270"
            }
        }, {
            "code": {
                "redeemed": "false", "code": "48c02f7bd35271de0aa215209b0a390f", "message": "code already used"
            }
        } ]
});

for (var code in data.codes) {
    console.log(code) // prints 0
    console.log(code[0].id) // prints 0
}
```

How can I access the inner objects separately ?

Comment: I don't see an "id" property anywhere.

Comment: did you use JSON.parse to actually build the JSON into a JSO?

Comment: `yourarray['codes'][0]...`?

Comment: And as he stated before, i don't see an id segment within your JSON

Comment: JSON doesn't allow the outer `()` or the trailing `;`.

Comment: @user1689607: In javascript, the `()` or `;` are okay.

Comment: @user1689607 -- it's not JSON. It's a JavaScript object. The whole thing isn't one big string, so it's not JSON.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The OP is calling it JSON.

Comment: @user1689607: Fair enough ;)

Comment: @Norguard: Yes, but the OP calls it JSON. If it's just a `({...});` sitting in the JavaScript code, it's useless. If it's actually server-side markup being shown, then the `()` and `;` are invalid. If you look at the questions revisions, the code segments were originally separate, so OP seemed to be referring to server-side JSON markup.

Comment: @user1689607 Yes. But again, if it was server-side markup which was printed ***directly to the page*** using an include or an echo, into the `script` tag, then it would land on the page as a full-fledged JS object, versus being streamed in, in text, through an `XMLHttpRequest`, unless, of course, it was echoed into a pair of single-quotes (and there were no apostrophes in the data, or the were escaped), or double-quotes (and every field-name was escaped). So it really comes down to knowing how it's stored and how its delivered. And really, it would be better to just auto-generate server-side.

Comment: @Norguard: Yeah, we don't know. My only point is that OP is calling it JSON, and as JSON it's invalid. If it's actually directly in a JavaScript program, its useless because it's not referenced. Either way it's fubar.

Comment: yes i meant - code not id. that wasnt the issue. The person who answered understood and answered. cheers guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output each individual `"code"` object:

```
// First, assign your data to a variable:
var data = ({
    "codes": [ {
        "code": {
            "redeemed": "true", "retailer": "R1", "code": "ab11845b55b3ef1c3f137a35dbdfb270"
        }
    }, {
        "code": {
            "redeemed": "false", "code": "48c02f7bd35271de0aa215209b0a390f", "message": "code already used"
        }
    } ]
});

// (I use the "c" temprary variable here because it's shorter)
var c = data.codes;
// Loop through all the codes.
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    // Log the specific code at [i].
    console.log(c[i].code);  // Output a "code" object.
}
```

You can then use:

```
c[i].code.redeemed;
c[i].code.retailer;
c[i].code.code;
c[i].code.message;
```

These will however return `undefined` when they're not set as a property of the specific `"code"` object.

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DFkJr/)**

Comment: got it with data.codes[0].code.id which is similar to here. thanks

Comment: I assume that with `id` you mean one of the properties like `redeemed` or `retailer`?

Answer (score 0):

assuming what you had added:

```
window.json_obj = ({"codes":[{"code":{"redeemed":"true","retailer":"R1","code":"ab11845b55b3ef1c3f137a35dbdfb270"}},{"code":{"redeemed":"false","code":"48c02f7bd35271de0aa215209b0a390f","message":"code already used"}}]});

console.log(json_obj.codes[0]['code']['code']);

// or
// console.log(json_obj.codes[0].code.code);
```

Comment: for future references, do a console.log(json_obj) in the firebug, and click on the element "logged" and analyze it in the DOM tab

Comment: You don't need the bracket notation, here. (Especially the first `['code']`), since it's a default / mandatory (non-dynamic) property.

Comment: Oh, whoops, missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywaFz/)**

```
console.log( obj.codes[0].code.retailer );
console.log( obj.codes[1].code.message );
```

Outputs

> R1
>   code already used

None of the objects have an `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

First:

Your JSON should not be in the parens, if you have no reason for it to be:

```
(<JSON>);
```

If that's all you're doing, it isn't going to let you access it.
You need to assign it to a variable...

```
var data = { codes : [ { code : "...", ...}, ... ] };
```

Once you do that, you have access like:

```
data.codes[i].code.code;
data.codes[i].code.redeemed;
```

PS: if it's not a full string

```
'{ "codes":[{"code":"...",...},...]}'
```

then it's not a JSON object, it's a JavaScript object.
Yes, that sounds picky.
But it all comes down to if you need to parse it and how, before you can use it properly.

Answer (score -1):

the for (var stuff in whatever) returns you the index of the object.
So basically, to access your object you have to do

```
console.log(data.codes[code]);
console.log(data.codes[code].id);
```

and please format your json in a readable way next time, hard to read here :)